# How to include the type of a parameter with its declaration when documenting with restructured text/Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am familiar with documenting the parameters of a Python function using 2 lines like so:

```
def get_market_history(self, market, count):
    """
    Used to retrieve the latest trades that have occured for a
    specific market.

    /market/getmarkethistory

    :param market: String literal for the market (ex: BTC-LTC)
    :type market: str
```

but I understand that for simple types you can include the type in the `:param` line, thus only needing one line instead of two. But I forgot the syntax for that and would appreciate an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:param str sender: The person sending the message` from [documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html#info-field-lists)